# Uploading images to a web page using asp.net, vb.script and using access as my db

Tags: asp.net, vbscript

Any help?
My code is as follows;

```
Imports System.IO
Imports System.Data
Imports System.Data.SqlClient 
Imports System.Data.OleDb

Partial Class Gallery
    Inherits System.Web.UI.Page

    Dim dbInsert As New OleDb.OleDbCommand
    Dim dbConnect As New OleDb.OleDbConnection
    Dim Line As String = Environment.NewLine
    Dim Message As String
    Dim dt As New DataTable()



    Protected Sub BtnUpload_Click(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles BtnUpload.Click

        Dim connection As New OleDbConnection("Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source = " & _
       Server.MapPath("App_Data\Web.accdb"))

        If FileUpload1.PostedFile IsNot Nothing Then
            Dim FileName As String = Path.GetFileName(FileUpload1.PostedFile.FileName)
            Dim Picture As String = TxtPicturename.Text

            'Save files to disk
            FileUpload1.SaveAs(Server.MapPath("GalleryPics/" & FileName))

            Dim strQuery As String = "insert into Picture (FileName, FilePath)" _
             & " values(@FileName, @FilePath)"

            Dim cmd As New SqlCommand(strQuery)
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@FileName", FileName)
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@FilePath", "Gallery/" & FileName)
            cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text

            Dim sql As String = "INSERT INTO Picture (PictureID, Picturename, CategoryNo) VALUES ('" & TxtPicturename.Text & "','" & FileUpload1.FileName & "');"
            dbInsert.CommandText = sql
            dbInsert.CommandType = CommandType.Text
            dbInsert.Connection = connection
            dbInsert.ExecuteNonQuery()
            MsgBox("Pictue successfully uploaded for " + Line + TxtPicturename.Text)

        End If

    End Sub
    Function checkFiletype(ByVal filename As String) As Boolean
        Dim ext As String = Path.GetExtension(filename)
        Select Case ext.ToLower()
            Case ".gif"
                Return True
            Case ".prg"
                Return True
            Case ".jpg"
                Return True
            Case "jpeg"
                Return True
            Case Else
                Return False
        End Select
    End Function

    Protected Sub Page_Load(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Me.Load




    End Sub
End Class
```

Comment: You need to provide some information's about your problem. Your code have many points that may not work if they have not setup correctlry, Like the database, the directories, the sql run. And you are the only one that you can debug it and find the real problem - that you do not even say to us.

Comment: I agree with @aristos you need to tell us exactly what problem you're having and if possible if an exception is being thrown which one!

Comment: The problem is that the pictures are uploading to an external file called galleryPics and then the program crashes! 
Sorry for the lack of information!

Comment: Its not hitting the database at all!

Comment: Your folder "GalleryPics" exist in the same folder as this page?

Comment: Yes it is!Its with my database and the project!

Comment: @Darren Is there an easier way of retrieving pictures from the desktop and then displaying them on the web page?

Comment: no, you have to upload them. As the others have said, post the actual error message you get.

Comment: @Darren it said:"ExecuteNonQuery requires an open and available Connection. The connection's current state is closed."

Comment: put `dbConnect.Open()` before `Dim cmd As New SqlCommand(strQuery)` Added an answer for you

Comment: @Darren it crashed and said internet cannot display the web page???

Comment: @Darren it seems to say nothing is going into the next statement?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You haven't got an open connection to your Database before trying to run your query.

put `dbConnect.Open()` before trying to use your query.

I.E

```
            dbConnect.Open() ''<------ HERE
            Dim cmd As New SqlCommand(strQuery)
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@FileName", FileName)
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@FilePath", "Gallery/" & FileName)
            cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text
```

Don't forget to close it when you're finished with it too... I.E

```
            dbInsert.ExecuteNonQuery()
            dbConnect.Close() '' <--------- HERE
```

**UPDATE**

See this tutorial for a good example of inserting.
http://idealprogrammer.com/net-languages/code-samples/vbnet-aspnet-sql-command-insert-statement-source-code/

Comment: @Darren- That's what I tried and then it crashed and said there was nothing getting passed through after?

Comment: @Darren-Error message:"The ConnectionString property has not been initialized."